# Why am i not able to access the second token using StringTokenizer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, split, stringtokenizer

I am attempting to split a number of orders into the quantity and item name. I am already splitting the list into seperate lines then attempting to split the lines at a ":" to seperate the quantity and name. I know the lines are being split correctly and displaying the right things, and the quantity splits off and shows fine but for some reason the item name is inaccessable and throws a java.util.NoSuchElementException when trying to reference it.

I have used .split() and have now moved to the StringTokenizer, but that still does not work

```
 for (String item : orderItems) {
            StringTokenizer orderTokens = new StringTokenizer(item, ":");
            String count = orderTokens.nextToken().trim();
            String itemName = orderTokens.nextToken().trim();
```

Depending on the input, I end up with a few lines that look something like : 1 : Lamb Korma
3 : Open Chicken Sandwich

When displaying the quantity it works fine and will give me 1 3, but when i try to access the names, i would expect it to simply display Lamb Korma Open Chicken Sandwich and it just throws an error instead

```
2019-10-30 14:09:15.099 14658-14658/com.example.assignment1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.assignment1, PID: 14658
    java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.StringTokenizer.nextToken(StringTokenizer.java:349)
        at com.example.assignment1.activities.MenuFragment.saveOrder(MenuFragment.java:229)
        at com.example.assignment1.activities.MenuFragment$1.onClick(MenuFragment.java:158)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7125)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7102)
        at android.view.View.access$3400(View.java:801)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27301)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
```

Comment: Please show what your input is.

Comment: For a normal example `String str = "1:2:3";
     String []arr = str.split(":");
     System.out.println(arr[0]);
     System.out.println(arr[1]);
     System.out.println(arr[2]);`

Comment: I cant show the exact input because it depends on user input but it formats as "number : Food Item;"

Comment: this is what populates the list it uses List<String> orderItems = Arrays.asList(orderTotal.split(";"));

Comment: Well further splitting on `:` should work as per my above comment. Of course, GIGO

Comment: Check whether `orderTokens` has more elements using `orderTokens.hasMoreElements()` in a loop condition and print all tokens. See what you get.

Comment: something like `while( orderTokens.hasMoreElements() ) { System.out.println( orderTokens.nextToken() ); }`

Comment: print all `item` of `orderItems` like this and see what actual tokens are you getting.

Comment: This is the console output of my orderItems: [3 : Green Salad Lunch, 
    2 : Lamb Korma, 
    3 : Open Chicken Sandwich, 
    1 : Beef Noodle Salad, 
    ]

Comment: fixed! turns out i had a floating \n inside my input that was messing with it. changed the first split to include ;/n and everything works fine now